# $.get and callback executed before its time

Tags: jquery, callback, get

This function, loads using $.get the content and in callback i call a jquery plugin (flip) function that 'plays' (gives an animation effect) with the new content,

```
function editar_item(id, tipo) {
    var div = 'link';
    if (tipo == 0) {} else if (tipo == 1) {
        div = 'pregunta';
    } else if (tipo == 2) {
        div = 'file';
    }

    $.get('/includes/router.php?que=editar_item&id=' + id + '&tipo=' + tipo, function (data) {
        $("#" + div + id).flip({
            direction: 'tb',
            content: data,
            color: '#F9F9F9',
            onEnd: function () {
                console.log('when the animation has already ended');
            }
        });

    });
    return false;
}
```

It works, but the jquery plugin call its executed before the content it's loaded and i can't see the 'effect' properly,

any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback should be the third parameter, you're using it as the second. Try:

```
$.get('/includes/router.php?que=editar_item&id='+id+'&tipo='+tipo, {},  function(data) {
   // ...etc
```

Comment: AFAIK the data parameter is optional. However, you should use it instead of building a query string manually.

Comment: Agreed, it is optional, but you need to specify something in that slot so that the callback isn't assigned to the wrong parameter.

Comment: I think jQuery is smart enough to test if the second parameter is callable and in this case use it as the success callback instead of the data.

Comment: i am getting same result (cache cleared), is there 'return false' in the right  place?